# How enable detailed error messages in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5, and I realized that in this version, the errors seems a bit 'user-friendly'... How to get the detailed error messages again?

For example: before, with this code:

`abort(500, 'The server is on fire');`

i saw this message "The server is on fire". Now, all I see is "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that the fire brigade has passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're aborting with a 500 code. What Laravel will eventually do is check if there is a an error view relating to that error code (which there is) and in turn display that view.

Out of the box Laravel comes with a 404, 419, 429, 500, 503 error views.

I would suggest using a code that is more appropriate for your situation (if possible). Here's a list of some of the error codes https://httpstatuses.com/.

Failing that you could override the default behaviour by adding the following to your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` class:

```
/**
 * Render the given HttpException.
 *
 * @param  \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException  $e
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
protected function renderHttpException(HttpException $e)
{
    $status = $e->getStatusCode();

    if ($status == 500 && config('app.debug')) {
        return $this->convertExceptionToResponse($e);
    }

    return parent::renderHttpException($e);
```

Essentially, this will bypass looking for the `500.blade.php` error view and should then display the stack with whoops. Please note that this is not tested against an actual 500 error so I'm not sure if it will work for that (I can't think of why it wouldn't but I just wanted to mention it).